# Magento inheriting category settings

Tags: php, inheritance, magento, categories

Is it somehow possible when i add a category in my magento store, it inherits the settings of the parent category?

// Roland

Comment: To clarify, you're specifically talking about the 'Is Anchor?' property which you want to have set by default and on any existing categories, correct?

Comment: Yes, but my guess would be if its possible for the "Is Anchor" property, it should be possible for all settings/properties offcourse.

I see no reason to exclude one property from the the other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, no. However, you could probably write a module relatively easy which would observe an event (probably called catalog_category_before_save) and it would copy the data from the parent category before saving it. Some properties obviously must be unique so you'd have to predetermine which ones you want to copy.

See this wiki article for how to create modules that observe events: [Event-Observer Method](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)
See this pdf for a list of events: [Magento Events Cheat Sheet](http://activecodeline.com/magento-event-hooks-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Proberly the way to go indeed. Thanks for the useful links.